# protoc executable unable to find object detection .protos file in tensorflow models

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, protoc

I am trying to work with the object detection api by tensorflow but was unable to install that properly. I looked up every solution in the internet and everything was in vain. **Below is the error message I am getting:**

> “C:\Program Files\protoc-3.5.0-win32\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
>
> object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are in which directory?
You can set the Path variable to point to protoc.exe and run the command from object detection directory